# Network access to PCs that use Windows Hello

Tags: windows-10, windows-networking, windows-hello

Our PCs at home have been updated to the April 2018 Update of Windows 10 and they're suggesting that we replace our passwords with Windows Hello. I've never used Windows Hello before, but I understand that it's a biometric login mechanism. So if that's the case, how can we access each other's PCs through the network? We currently use passwords to access network shares and Remote Desktop. I'm unsure if I should enable Windows Hello in case we all lose access to sharing each other's resources as biometric authentication is just for access to the local machine. Can someone confirm whether or not you can continue using Windows Hello-enabled computers through the network?

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify:

Q1. Can I still login to a Windows 10 Hello-enabled PC remotely via RDP using a traditional username & password?

Q2. Can I also still use a username & password to access a network share (i.e. map a drive letter) which is hosted on a remote Windows 10 computer that uses Windows Hello?

Q3. If the answer to the above questions is no, then is there another authentication method I must use instead?

Comment: Even if you use Windows Hello you can still use the username and password if you want.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT thanks for the answer. I simply want to continue being able to login to a remote Windows 10 PC via RDP using the traditional password method. I also want to access network shares by mapping a drive to the remote machine by supplying a password. My question is can I still do that if I enable Windows Hello on the remote machine?

Answer (score 1):

According to the moderator on this [TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e48f3809-617f-4a5b-8f4e-8f231d47addc/using-rdp-to-login-in-a-windows-hello-pin-secured-pc?forum=win10itpronetworking) post. . .

> Windows 10 made some changes to the way the biometric authentication,
>   including fingerprint, works in order to improve security. Because of
>   this, RDP with fingerprint login is not currently supported in Windows
>   10.
>
> - [Virtual Smart Card Overview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn593708%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
>
> [Carl Fan](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/profile/carl%20fan/?ws=usercard-mini) (MSFT CSG)

You could consider disabling the **Windows Hello** feature. . .

> If you have setup Windows Hello facial recognition it is very easy to
>   remove:
>
> 1. All Settings
> 2. Accounts
> 3. Sign-in Options
> 4. Under Windows Hello hit the **Remove** button. You do not need to
>      restart the computer.
>
> <sub>[source](https://www.windowscentral.com/disabling-windows-hello-save-battery-surface-pro-4)</sub>